# Setting Up Devise & Sendgrid on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, sendgrid

My site is hosted on Heroku and I installed the Sendgrid Add-On as it looked almost too good to be true - but so far none of the email functionality is working. I have read the documentation and it clearly says just add-the add on - is more configuration required to get Devise working?

When I select 'send me new password' I get a 404 page which makes me think there is more to this. Like how does Sendgrid know/where to use the pre-installed Devise templates?

Thx.

Comment: A 404 error is an error in your Devise routes. Verify your routes with `rake routes | grep devise`. Devise uses your ActionMailer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I just set up Devise and SendGrid this morning and have no problems. I'm going to resume the steps I took.

First, install Devise and SendGrid. Congratulations, you've already done that ;)

Then, for production, add this to your files:

`config/initializers/devise.rb` :

```
config.mailer_sender = "mail-to-send@from.com"
```

---

Set up Rails [ActionMailer to use SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html#-Configure-ActionMailer-to-Use-SendGrid)

`config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your.websitedomain.com' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name            => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port                 => 587,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :domain               => "yourdomain.com"
}
```

And everything's working great with that. Sign up confirmations, password recovery...

Also, you should use [Logging Expanded](http://addons.heroku.com/logging) (it's Free!) and check your logs with `heroku logs --tail` (for real time).
If you still get errors, post your logs.

Have a good day !

Comment: your solution worked perfectly. The instructions on Heroku don't include the code config.mailer_sender = "mail-to-send@from.com". Thx.

Comment: so far only the password reset email is working. Do I need to change something for the 'new' user' to work too?

Comment: Nope, everything worked for me. Password reset, subscription etc... Check your heroku logs to get your error.

Comment: is the subscription email you mention the :confirmable method, so when a new user signs up they have to click on a link in the email in order to log in?

Comment: @ubique Yes, exactly. That's weird that you can send password recovery but not the confirmation mail.

Comment: is the sendgrid password the same that my heroku account?, if is not, can i set it here? https://sendgrid.com/user/account

Answer (score 1):

I've used the sendgrid Add-On and it really should *just work*. Like you said, even [the docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid) say so:

> Rails apps using ActionMailer will just work, no setup is needed after the add-on is installed.

So, this makes me think something else is going on. Have you tried using the [`heroku logs`](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log_retrieval) command to see if your application is logging any errors?

Comment: "Note that a plugin to automatically configure ActionMailer for Rails is installed on our Bamboo stack. The following settings are necessary on Cedar, or for non-Rails apps using ActionMailer on Bamboo."

Comment: Note that when I originally answered the question two years ago, Bamboo was still the default stack.

Comment: Yep no worries, just trying to keep this relevant and up to date :)