# Devise Signup button not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app in which I am using devise gem for user signup and login. I followed all the steps to use devise:
added following to gemfile

```
gem 'devise'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

After executing

```
rails g devise:install
```

I ran the following command

```
rails g devise user
```

After this I did

```
rake db:migrate
```

Everything goes well, devise gem got installed migration was also successful and the url

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

shows the signup form. But after filling the data on clicking signup button nothing is happening. No error on console. No data is being inserted to the table. Any help would be appreciable.

console log

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-06 15:04:56 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /home/ajeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered /home/ajeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (28.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 278ms (Views: 257.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

User devise migration file content

```
def change
create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at

  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
 end
end
```

Database is mysql
content of routes.rb file

```
devise_for :users
root 'home#index'
get 'home/index'
```

Comment: can you please post your log and user model

Comment: @ Ajeet : Your steps are correct.It should work.BTW which DB you are using.

Comment: Have you set your `root to:`?

Comment: Have you seen the log about POST in your console?

Comment: As above, need some more info to debug - Try some debugging in the console e.g. try to create a new user and see what errors you get. btw it should be rails g devise User with a capital

Comment: creating a new user is working via console.

Answer (score 1):

In your User Model add :confirmable and set your root to: in your routes.rb.

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

Your routes.rb should look like something like this:

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

I forgot to add, please uncomment these lines:

```
 ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

You can use Heroku to get a free SendGrid account for e-mail activation.

Bottom of your dev environment:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Comment: You need a mailer setup. What have you done for that?

Comment: for that i have put the following lines in config/environment/development.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

Comment: What's in the console log after submitting the sign up form?

Comment: @tangrufus the signup form not getting submitted. Console doesn't have any output

Comment: @AjeetKhan if you do not have a mailer setup nothing will get sent.

Comment: @JonathanMusso for that i have put the following lines in config/environment/development.rb config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

Comment: @JonathanMusso Nothing

Comment: @AjeetKhan This is your problem. Take a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019083/setting-up-devise-sendgrid-on-heroku

Comment: @JonathanMusso But I want the devise without email functionality

Comment: Remove `:confirmable` & `:recoverable` from model, and remove related columns in DB if you don't want the devise email functionality